# Is there an analytical solution to this ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am not very knowledgeable in the field so I apologize in advance if this question might look naive. But is there an analytical solution to a differential equation that looks like this :
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\theta}{\mathrm{d}t^2}-a^{2}\cot \theta \csc ^2\theta +b\sin \theta =0$$
$a,b$  are real constants, and $b>0$.
I have tried to solve this with Mathematica, and I could only solve it numerically.

Comment: There's no closed form solution if $a=0$. Technically there is an analytical solution though, because it can be solved with a series. I'm thinking the same is true for $a^2>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be reduced to an implicit solution including special functions. Multiply by $\theta'$ and integrate to get
\begin{align}
\theta'\theta''+b\sin(\theta)\theta'-a^2\cot(\theta)\csc(\theta)^2\theta'=0,\\\\
\frac12 (\theta')^2-b\cos(\theta)-\frac12 a^2\csc(\theta)^2=C,\\\\
\int\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\sqrt{C+2b\cos(\theta)+a^2\csc(\theta)^2}}=t+C'.
\end{align}
Take  $\cos(\theta)=x$ to get
\begin{align}
\int \frac{-\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(C+2bx)+a^2}},
\end{align}
which [Wolfram Alpha can give a solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%201%2Fsqrt%28%281-x%5E2%29%28C%2B2bx%29%2Ba%5E2%29%20dx) to in terms of the [elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), though the notation used is a bit cluttered. Perhaps Mathematica can give you a more clear integral solution.